# set credentials to SQL Server DB in Excel files

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, powerquery, credentials

I try to distribute to my collegaues the excel file with some data taken from companys SQL Server Database.
The problem I am facing right now is how to provide credentials together with this file so users wouldn't have to input these and know the password?
Currently I do the queries directly from Power Query but not see if somewhere I can set the credentials to be "remembered" with file.
If I am not mistaken, the login and password can be included in the VBA macro, but only when we see the SQL query syntax in the "Connetions" tab but not in the Power Query editor in "Queries" tab. So how to do it? Maybe some solution is to view query created from Power Query on "View Native Query" view, copy its and create in the form of "connections" where it will be possible to pass login data to it via VBA (eg when opening the file?). Anybody can help??

Comment: Is using a Windows Authentication an option?

Comment: Probably needs to be by username and password :(